# How do I organize an uneven matrix of many calculations in pandas / numpy / pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am calculating a model that requires a large number of calculations in a big matrix, representing interactions between households (numbering N, roughly 10E4) and firms (numbering M roughly 10E4).  In particular, I want to perform the following steps:

1. X2 is an N x M matrix representing pairwise distance between each household and each firm.  The step is to multiply every entry by a parameter gamma.
2. delta is a vector length M.  The step is to broadcast multiply delta into the rows of the matrix from 1.
3. Exponentiate the matrix from 2.
4. Calculate the row sums of the matrix from 3.
5. Broadcast division division by the row sum vector from 4 into the rows of the matrix from 3.
6. w is a vector of length N.  The step is to broadcast multiply w into the columns of the matrix from 5.
7. The final step is to take column sums of the matrix from 6.

These steps have to be performed 1000s of times in the context of matching the model simulation to data.  At the moment, I have an implementation using a big NxM numpy array and using matrix algebra operations to perform the steps as described above.

**I would like to be able to reduce the number of calculations by eliminating all the "cells" where the distance is greater than some critical value r.**

How can I organize my data to do this, while performing all the operations I need to do (exponentiation, row/column sums, broadcasting across rows and columns)?

The solution I have in mind is something like storing the distance matrix in "long form", with each row representing a household / firm pair, rather than the N x M matrix, deleting all the invalid rows to get an array whose length is something less than NM, and then performing all the calculations in this format.  In this solution I am wondering if I can use pandas dataframes to make the "broadcasts" and "row sums" work properly (and quickly). How can I make that work?

(Or alternately, if there is a better way I should be exploring, I'd love to know!)

Comment: Don't delete, use masks if possible. Use NumPy for performance if you are working with regular data (numeric only).

Comment: @Divakar Thank you!  Working on making it work, but I think masks are what I needed

Comment: @Divakar So far, I am not getting the hoped-for performance improvements out of masks, whether I use masked arrays or a boolean array for a mask.  Is it helpful clarification that the purpose of eliminating "cells" is explicitly to reduce the number of calculations, not just to discard unwanted data?